# Ajax & JS: how to keep a dropdown open during an ajax refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a chat in a web page having its components refreshed in ajax.
I have a userlist and when clicking on the name of a user, a number of actions appear in a drop down.

but, when the userlist is being refreshed in ajax, it automatically closes the drop down. Giving only 1.5s max to the user to click on the action .... not ideal.

So, i am looking for a way for the dropdown menu to stay open, even if a refresh occurs.

html:

```
            <div class="col-md-3 mobile_phone pr-0 mt-1 pl-0 border border-dark">
                    <nav class="container room_display  p-0"  id="roominfo">
                          <!--ajax refresh here-->
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

Ajax:

```
setInterval(function(){displayUsers();},1500);

function displayUsers()
    {
        $.post('core/chat_logic.php?action=roomAndUsers',function(response)
        {
            $('.room_display').html(response);
        });
    }
```

php "action=roomAndUsers"

```
case 'roomAndUsers':
        

    $roomNusers=unserialize(file_get_contents ("../cache_useronline.txt"));
    foreach($roomNusers as $room => $value)
    {
        ?>
            <div class="room">
                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $room;?>" checked>
                <label for="<?php echo $room;?>" class="m-0"><?php echo $room;?></label>
                <div class="user_list">
                    <ul class="userul list-unstyled">
                        <!-- user list room-->
                        <?php 
                        foreach($roomNusers[$room]['users'] as $user_name)
                        {
                            ?>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn text-white p-0  dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <img src="smiles/16x16/<?php echo $user_name['0'];?>" class="img li pr-2" alt="quixote"><?php echo $user_name['1'];?> <?php echo $user_name['2'];?>
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <button class="btn text-white py-0 px-2 d-block">Private Message</button> 
                                <button class="btn text-white py-0 px-2 d-block">Invite</button>
                                <button class="btn text-white py-0 px-2 d-block">Ignore</button>
                                <button class="btn text-white py-0 px-2 d-block">Profile</button>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php      
                }
        
break;
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You are refreshing the html on every interval so it makes sense that the dropdown would close. Maybe the the refresh is removing a class or focused element that opens the dropdown and replacing it.

I think the way to fix this would be to keep track of your current rooms and users in state client side, and then parse out any added or removed elements from what the server returns. I would suggest returning a JSON object of rooms and users instead of all the html, including a unique identifier, and just doing some simple DOM manipulation client side.

So instead of `$('.room_display').html(response);` you could check for differences between the users on display and users returned by the server. In the example assume that the data returned by server has a users property with an array of user objects with an ID property, and that you have attached the userID as a data attribute on the li elements of the user list:

```
const currentList = $('.room_display').find('.dropdown');


   // add user from server response if not in currentList
   
   response.users.forEach(function(user){
     let isInList = false;
     currentList.each(function(el){
       if (el.data('ID') === user.ID){
         isInList = true;
       } 
     });

     if (!isInList) {
       const html = //generate user html
       $('.room_display').find('.userul').append(html);
     }
   })

   // append user elements who are not in the current list but in the server response

  currentList.each(function(el){
    let isInList = false;
    response.users.forEach(function(user){
      if (user.ID === el.data('ID')) {
        isInList = true;
      }
    });

    if (!isInList) {
      $.remove(el);
    }
  })
```

There are a number of ways to optimize this, like sending the current users to the server and only returning the difference between the users to the client, so the client only has to append or remove elements from the server response.

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to write this post. 
very instructive for a new comer like me. 
That give lot so f clues on where to look up next.